# android:versioncode and android:versionname how to make my sdk compatible

Tags: android, version, manifest

I just decompiled an APK so that I can see the how the app works.
I imported the project but it's almost completely red for errors.
Do I have to change something in the Manifest?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.1"    package="com.jesstech.bluetooth.bledemo"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <application android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="false">
            <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.jesstech.bluetooth.bledemo.DeviceScanActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.jesstech.bluetooth.bledemo.DeviceControlActivity" />
            <service android:name="com.jesstech.bluetooth.bledemo.BluetoothLeService" android:enabled="true" />
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Question about reverse engineering is typically not allow in SO. Please consider rephrasing your question or remove this question entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Manifest should be this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jesstech.bluetooth.bledemo"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <application android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="false">
            <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.jesstech.bluetooth.bledemo.DeviceScanActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.jesstech.bluetooth.bledemo.DeviceControlActivity" />
            <service android:name="com.jesstech.bluetooth.bledemo.BluetoothLeService" android:enabled="true" />
        </application>
</manifest>
```

and for the sdk

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" /> depends on your SDK version
```